# how to extend default running timeout for azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to extend timeout for azure pipeline , my pipeline is always been canceled in 60minus

wondering how to re-set timeout on yaml for pipeline , I search one [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#define-a-single-job), but didn't work

[image]

screenshot#2[image]

Comment: You can only extend beyond 60 minutes on a private agent or when you have paid for additional parallel pipelines. Free accounts are limited to a Max job duration of 60 minutes.

Comment: thanks jessehouwing, I can extend timeout now based on your provided link.

Comment: We have paid for 4 parallel pipelines, but it still has the 60m timeout.  Did anyone find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

See the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations):

For free tier:

> Private project: One free parallel job that can run for up to **60** minutes each time, until you've used 1,800 minutes (30 hours) per month.

Comment: thanks navylover, actually my one job contains all cases, I need to extend timeout for this job like screenshot#2. how to extend timeout for one job.